# Laravel from database table to another table 1mill rows, slow

Tags: php, database, laravel

So basically, I got 2 tables. 
The first table contains 1 million rows or something, with an empty field called 'telefon'.

Now, I got a second table, which has the field values for 'telefon' in the other table.

I came up with this solution, but this takes forever. It has been an hour, and when inspecting the database table, only 1600 rows are done. Is there any faster ways of doing this? Thanks in advance.

```
DB::table('phones') -> orderBy('id') -> chunk(100, function($old) {
        foreach ($old as $x) {
            DB::table('companies')
                -> where('organisasjonsnummer', $x -> businessCode)
                -> update([
                    'telefon' => $x -> contact
                ]);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh, foreach + queries is almost always bad. If I am not mistaken, you would like to do this:

```
UPDATE companies, phones SET companies.telefon = phones.contact WHERE companies.organisasjonsnummer = phones.businessCode
```

It may be very slow if there's no index on `companies.organisasjonsnummer` and `phones.businessCode` columns, but it can take a lot of time to index them now as well, so I'm not sure if there's any benefit to index them now if they won't be used later. Anyway, using a single query should be faster at least to some extent.

Comment: Yes, that is what I try to do. No, they're not indexed. 
But I agree, this would go faster, but how would I write this in Laravels query-builder? Should I just use `DB::raw(...)`?
Thanks.

Comment: You can just wrap it into `DB::statement()` since there are no parameters to be escaped, it's just a plain query.

Comment: Glad to hear that, and hope it won't take an hour per 1k records :))

Comment: It took 70 seconds to do 700k records, so it whent fine. :D

Answer (score 1):

Always remember, when you use Eloquent/SQL inside a loop, you will run a command for each round.
The same applies for lazy loading.

In this case you should use `\DB::statement("put your sql here");` or in this case `\DB::update("put your update here");`, let the database do the service for you and be happy!.